# Understanding the Uncertainly Principle in Stern–Gerlach experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

***Question is at the bottom, some background info***

I was watching a lecture where they considered for simplicity sake that the spins were represented as two properties : Hardness (Hard and Soft) and Color (Black and White). And that some experiments were run that use 2 black box apparatuses. A Color box that has three apertures, one input port and two output ports where the black and white electrons come out from. So, it's positionally distinguishable. Similarly there's a Hardness box that has three apertures, one input port and two output ports where the hard and soft electrons come out from

[image]

**Experiment 1** Try's to test if given that an electron is white would we be able to determine the hardness. It concludes that Color and Hardness are INDEPENDENT PROPERTIES with no CORRELATION i.e. Color does not influence Hardness and vise versa. Measuring the color gives no predictive power in determining hardness. But we know that there is a 50/50 chance of the output.

An additional Experiment (sorry, no image here), just imagine it. If you take two color boxes, one placed after the other, say the second one taking the input that comes out of the white port. It was found that with 100% confidence the output from the second box was white. This concludes that the results from the Color and similarly the Hardness boxes are REPEATABLE - A PERSISTENT PROPERTY.

[image]

Now the second experiment places a Hardness box in between Two Color boxes, as mentioned above, if we placed two color boxes, we found out about the repeatable nature. Could the same hold true here?

1. Input to the first Color box are a set of Random electrons
2. Output from the first Color box has a 50/50 chance of coming out as Black or White electrons
3. Hardness box with Input aperture placed in line with the White output, we know from Experiment one that there is no correlation. Hence, there is a 50/50 chance that the output is Hard or Soft electrons.
4. Color box with Input aperture placed in line with the soft output. We'd think from the Additional Experiment that since the properties are persistent, the **natural expectation** since the white electron entered the hardness box that if we placed another color box is that we'd get white. Hence, giving 100% confidence that the output is White.
5. Shockingly! The experiment found that that the output had exactly (to experimental tolerances) a 50/50 chance of coming out as white or black.

So, the persistent property was disrupted with the insertion of a Hardness block. Similar results were found when there were two Hardness boxes and one Color box and other combinations of outputs.

The lecturer notes that there are also no known additional features of the incident electrons that determine which port the electrons come out of. As of we know, it is completely random.

This tells a very uncomfortable truth which was hard to digest that there is something intrinsically an unpredictable, non-deterministic and random about physical processes that were observed in a laboratory. There is no way to determine a  priori to see whether an electron will come out as black or white in the above experiment.

And that the probability of the outcome is FORCED upon us by observation

FINALLY:

As a curious consequence, we cannot build a Color & Hardness box (a meaningful box that tells the color and hardness). Below is how it'd look like.

[image]

The problem with this as we saw in Experiment 2 is that the color is not persistent!

He says we can't build such a box, just cuz we're crude, but because of something deeper, intrinsic, and in principle which is encoded in experiment 2.

He concludes to say:

1. It doesn't mean anything to say the electron is white and hard
2. If it's told that an electron White and Hard and you measure if it's White, it'll be a 50/50 chance of being White.
3. THE UNCERTAINITY PRINCIPLE - there is some observable properties of a system that are incompatible with each other. To say that it cannot be hard and white simultaneously.

**QUESTION**
Even though we cannot know/observe through experimentation that these two properties can exist at the same time. Since Hardness and Color are INDEPENDENT PROPERTIES, how can we still leave out the possibility of both of them existing at the same time. I don't understand the uncertainty principle's usage in this case. What does he mean by it not being meaningful to know that Color and Hardness exist at the same time.

Comment: Tl;dr. That lecture seems like a desperate attempt to explain the uncertainty principle without introducing Hermitian operators that don't commute. I'd rather spend time on that.

Comment: I see, I'll try to look at that then. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @KurtG. can you try to explain uncertainty principle in that context tho? It's frustrating just not being able to understand a view point.

Comment: There are plenty of resources you can find easily that explain UC in the proper context. Feel free to ask a *specific* question. There is no need for me to start a lecture on this topic here.

Answer (score 1):

I am also a new learner to the subject and would like to share what I understand so far informally. Hope it gives some intuition.

...............................................................

In quantum mechanics, **measurement changes things**. Measuring color here leaves the system in a state where a subsequent measurement of hardness has 50-50 chance of particle being hard.

The uncertainty principle arises due to the fact that measurement of color changes the probabilities of measuring hardness subsequently. (and vice-versa).

As an example, suppose you had a system with N  particles (N is a large number), N/3 measured to be hard, and 2N/3  measured to be not hard. If you pass this through the color measurement, and measure hardness again, the distribution of hard to not hard changes to about (N/2, N/2). Properties like (Color, Hardness) where this happens are called non- commuting.

There are other properties, say Bitterness (bitter/not-bitter), whose measurement does not change the probabilities of a subsequent measurement of hardness. So a N/3, 2N/3 distribution of hardness will continue in that state, even if you measure Bitterness in the middle. Properties like (Bitterness, Hardness) are called commuting.

In this sense, we can talk about a particle having (Bitterness, Hardness) at the same time, but not talk about having (Color, Hardness) at the same time.

I would refer you to Chapter 2 of Quantum Computation and Quantum Information  by Nielsen & Chuang for a rigorous treatment of the theory and mathematics of it.